# How to add a reference to a project in dotnet/cli (rc2)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net5, dotnet-cli

I have created a Web API dotnet core project and i would like to use an older C# library (.NET Framework 4.5)

My project.json looks like

```
...
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
       "imports": [
         "net451",
         //"dotnet5.6",
         //"dnxcore50",
         "portable-net45+win8"
         ],
  "dependencies": {
    "LibInternal": {
      "target": "project"
    }
  }
}
...
```

After adding a using in Startup.cs, i get the error - the type or namespace name "..." could not be found.

What is wrong?

Comment: Did `dotnet restore` succeed for you?

Comment: no, same error like before

Comment: Is your **LibInternal** C# Library folder present at the same level as your WebApi project's folder ? for e.g. parent folder should have two sub folders named YourWebApi and LibInternal. Only then `dotnet restore` of your webapi would restore LibInternal project successfully.